# Amazon S3 + Lambda + DynamoDB Website Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, stripe-payments, aws-lambda

I'm interested in hosting a website for a small business  (< 100 users / month) and I wanted to try going 'serverless'. I've read that using Amazon S3, Lambda and DynamoDB is a way to set this up, by hosting the front-end on S3, using Lambda functions to access the back-end, and storing data in DynamoDB. I'll need to run a script on page load to get data to display, save user profiles/allow logins, and acccept payments using Stripe or Braintree.

Is this a good situation to use this setup, or am I better off just using EC2 with a LAMP stack? Which is better in terms of cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a perfectly good solution, and will probably cost you nothing at all to host on AWS - literally pennies a month. I host several low traffic sites this way and it works well.

The only caveat would be, since your traffic is so slow, almost every time someone hits a page, if it needs to make any back-end calls, those lambda functions will likely need a 'cold-start', which may introduce a delay and cause the page to load a bit slower than if it had more traffic that tended to keep the lambda cache 'warm'.

Comment: What frameworks of languages do you recommend using to set this up?

Comment: I use both node.js and the C#/.net flavors for lambda - node.js seems like more of a 'first class' citizen in the lambda world, but lambda supports several languages. My typical solution is html/css/angular running on cloudfront/s3 talking to lambda on the backend.